# Turn link into URL when URL contains "="

Tags: vba

I am using the following VBA function to turn a link into a URL

```vb
Function GetURL(cell As Range)
    GetURL = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

I get `#VALUE` as a result

I believe it is because there is an "=" sign in the URL. Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: Replace the `=` with `%3D` - does the link work? If not, I'd say there is some other problem.

Comment: Please use proper formatting when writing questions and answers. // what's *inside* a variable does not "execute". // Where and how are you getting this result?

Comment: Your function should work for URLs not containing a document fragment (`#something`). The error is probably because you are passing a reference which is not a cell - for example `'A1'` instead of `Range("A1")`.